# Magento prices wrong in slider

Tags: magento, mage

I'm not very experienced with Magento so please bear with me.

I have a slider on a home page that displays a subset of "special" products. Some (not all) of these products are showing the price as £0.00, but when I click into that product on its view page, the price is showing correctly.

Both the slider's block and the view have the same transforms on the product before finally calling:

```
$this->getPriceHtml($_product, true)
```

The only difference between the two is that $this for the view is an instance of Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_View and the block for the slider is an instance of Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List - and that's where I've reached a standstill, I have no idea how to track down why the price is being returned differently in these two cases.

Edit: It only has this problem for products which are set as Bundle and for which the price is set as dynamic.

Answer (score 0):

Please replace your price code with below code

```
$_product->getFinalPrice();
```

I hope its useful for you!!

Comment: Hi Sanjay, getFinalPrice returns 0 for these products (again, only for this block, they return the correct price on the product view page)

Comment: Ah - actually it returns 0 for both the product view and the list on the homepage BUT the getPriceHtml does return the right price on the product view but not the list on the homepage. Hmm.

Comment: Old thread, but did you ever get anywhere with this? I've ran into similar issue before and was wondering how you resolve this?